# Non-Static Data Duration in Static Functions

Tags: c++

I would like to initialize a static array of abstract interfaces.  I'm just wondering if a call to a static function to build the data is a valid means of initialization.  What will the lifetime of the data that the pointer is pointing to in the code below look like?

```
typedef class FOO {
public:
    static const int** array_int;
    static const int** array_int_init();

} FOO;

const int** FOO::array_int_init()
{
    const int A = 5;
    const int B = 6;
    const int C = 7;

    const int* array_int[] = { &A, &B, &C };

    return &array_int[0];
}
const int** FOO::array_int = array_int_init();
```

Also what is the best way to find specifics about behaviors like this in the C++ specification?  I have N3225=10-0215 but even looking at the index and the content I find I would need to read a lot with no promise of an answer.

Comment: `typedef class Foo { ... } FOO;` is really not longer necessary in C++. A simple `class Foo { };` is absolutely enough.

Comment: @Polybos: In fact, it never was necessary in C++.

Comment: @sbi Sorry for lack of clarity :) I wanted to say: In C it was necessary, but in C++ it's no longer.

Comment: Does anybody mind if I do it anyway?  It helps me with my workflow templates, aliases, COM and so on ....  I will refrain here?? >.<

Comment: I don't mind the `typedef` a long as I don't have to work with your code ;) It's strange and leaves you wondering, whcih is a problem IMO.

Comment: In C++ you don't have to type `class FOO f` when initializing a var. `FOO f` is completely enough. That's why the typedef is unneded. Same applies to `structs`.

Comment: @Polybos: It's fine, really. (I up-voted your comment anyway.) I just wanted to avoid the possibility of someone attributing this to the new version of the standard or anything like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variables are locals and they will cease to exist when the function exits. If you need them to survive then declare both vars and array as static inside the function with

```
const int** array_int_init()
{
    static const int A = 5;
    static const int B = 6;
    static const int C = 7;

    static const int* array_int[] = { &A, &B, &C };

    return &array_int[0];
}
```

These static variables will last as long as the program and will be initialized the first time you call the function (note that in case of multithreading however some extra handling is needed if initialization is not as trivial as the case above).

Comment: @Tal, `array_int` is just a pointer and it can point to the static defined inside of `array_int_init()`, @6502 I don't think multithreading is an issue here (given how it's being called).

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I didn't notice that the static member was initialized by calling this function.

Comment: static function data will be held between calls but does it ever move?

Comment: @PrettyFlower, No, static data will not move. This solution should work for you.

Comment: @Nim: On many (all?) compilers initialization of a static is not protected by a mutex, so if initialization is non trivial and happens once threads are already running you may find problems. Of course here initialization is just a constant and doesn't matter, but in general it may require some care to get it working correctly in multithreaded environments. The common "singleton" pattern of simply using lazy initialization with a static to hold a class instance can be problematic with multithreading.

Comment: @6502, completely agreed, hence why I said "given how it's being called" :)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, it seems that instead of the method actually initializing the static data member 'array_int' it creates a local array with the same name and returns that as its return value. This actually causes 2 bugs:

1. The 'array_int' member is left uninitialized. EDIT: My mistake, didn't notice that you initialize the static member with the return value. Ignore this point.
2. The return value of 'array_int_init()' is the address of the local array, which will not be valid once the method returns. Actually, the values in that array point *themselves* to other local int variables, whose addresses will also not be valid once the function returns.

But, to answer your general question, yes - it is enough to call a static class function (it doesn't even have to return anything) to initialize static class members, and they will stay initialized until the program ends.

EDIT: Based on the comments, I guess there's some confusion here so I'll try to give a better explanation.

In the original code, there is a static data member called FOO::array_int. That data member is *not* initialized or accessed in the code.

There is also a local variable in the function array_int_init(), whose address is returned as the function's return value. Now, since both that static variable and all the int variables whose addresses are used to populate that array are all allocated on the stack, they are no longer valid once the function returns (meaning that accessing those addresses will result in undefined behavior). The reason it seems to work in VC10 is that you are accessing the returned array right after the function returns, before any other information is allocated on the stack that overwrites the previous data. That, however, will not work in a 'real' application.

Comment: 1.) array_int will be INITIALIZED by FOO::array_int_init()
2.) static data will remains throughout the lifetime of owning processes.

Comment: Which is exactly what I would expect except that if I run this code in VC10 everything is all very happily correct.  This of course led me to ask a rather silly question ....  [edit] with exception to the initialization I don't understand why you are saying that?

Comment: I don't see why this answer was marked down, both points are valid (the first contentious, it is initialized to crap - i.e the return value). @PrettyFlower, if it works, it's by pure luck - the correct way to do it, is as @6502 states in that answer.